# Prove $\int e^{x^{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function, error-function

I have to prove $\int e^{x^{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}$.

I aready know that $\int e^{x^{2}} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi} * erfi(x)}{2}$. What i cannot understand is how $\frac{erfi(x)}{2}$ get cancelled.

Thank you.

Comment: You make a confusion between the value of an integral and the antiderivative of a function.

Comment: Looking for an answer I thought about that too, but my professor gave me this exactly expression to prove: $\int e^{x^{2}} = \sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: Well, sometimes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ is just written as $\int$, but that's just sloppy notation and should be avoided when not clear from the context. However, the $-$ in $\mathrm e^{-x^2}$ is certainly missing!

Comment: @DavidSantana That is false, then, since the LHS represents a family of functions, while the RHS represents a number.

Comment: Yeah in it's current form the question isn't true

Comment: Ok, maybe the test is for us to prove that this equation is false or he wrote it wrong. Another question, if the LHS were $\int e^{-x^{2}}$, the expression would be true?

Comment: @DavidSantana you can read my *partial* answer below. No, it won't make the expression true since you haven't defined your bounds. ${\int e^{-x^2}dx}$ won't be a number, it will be a function in terms of $x$

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you meant ${\int e^{-x^2}dx}$ (correct me if I'm wrong). When you talk about the expression
$$
\int e^{-x^2}dx
$$
This is **not** going to just be ${\sqrt{\pi}}$. This is an anti-derivative - that is,
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int e^{-x^2}dx = e^{-x^2}
$$
But clearly
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{\pi}=0
$$
What your professor is probably meaning to ask you is to show
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}
$$
which is true. There is surprisingly more than one way to calculate this integral - polar coordinates, feynmans trick.... so it's difficult to give you the right guidance towards an answer that complements the material you have covered. Please edit the question and add more context

Answer (score 1):

you have a simple way of showing this with double integrals. Let :
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx $$ Now we get:
$$I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}dxdy $$
Now you can do a polar change of variable, with $r^2=x^2+y^2 $, and $dxdy=rdrd\theta$

$$I^2=\int_{r=0}^{\infty}\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} re^{-r^2}drd\theta=\pi\int_0^\infty 2re^{-r^2}dr\\
=\pi\left[-e^{-r^2} \right]_0^\infty=\pi$$

Hence the result :
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi} $$

Comment: This is all completely true, but I don't think this will help OP since (1) There is more than one way to calculate this integral, and we have no idea what material he has covered and (2) OP is actually confused about the question itself here

Answer (score -1):

$erf$ is a name we sometimes give to the primitive (anti-derivative) of the function $x \mapsto e^{-x^2}$, which cannot be expressed in the usual way. The reason we give it a name is because we know a few interesting properties about it. But in any case, since we don't know its expression, it's not gonna help us compute the integral of $e^{-x^2}$. You have to proceed otherwise...

Here's a hint: think about the expression $\left(\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x\right)^2$, and try to turn it into a simple integral, instead of a product of two integrals...

Comment: This is also all true, but again I don't think it's a super helpful answer since (1) We have no idea what OP currently knows / what his professor intended, since there is more than 1 way to solve this integral and (2) he doesn't actually seem to understand the question itself

Comment: Indeed, I do not actually understood my professor question and this subject because I am really new at this subject and this is a extra exercise, which is suppose to be a little hard for us. Ok, I will try upon it. Thank you